# Any good recursive tutorials? Python?

Tags: c++, python, recursion

Wondering if anyone could point me towards a good recursion tutorial. I am a bit rusty on it as I learned about it in my Data Structures class first semester. Would like to brush up on my recursion...any help?

Comment: [Stack Overflow question about recursive tutorials](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295817/any-good-recursive-tutorials-python)

Comment: Dammit you got there first Mark!  :)

Comment: That's so good it should've been mine!

Comment: Meh, how could I hope for a recursion question without a classic link-to-self joke! :P

Comment: If only it would show up in the "Linked" section on the right :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295817/any-good-recursive-tutorials-python/3295853#3295853).

More seriously…

Recursion is a way of solving problems that have a clearly defined base case (or cases, btu I'm keeping it simple here.)

For examples, the commonly cited factorial problem is a great one.

What does factorial do? Let's see some examples:

```
factorial(0) = 1
factorial(1) = 1
factorial(2) = 2
factorial(3) = 6
factorial(4) = 24
```

The factorial of a number is that number multiplied by the factorial of the number that comes before it, *unless* (now, this is the base case) the number is 0. The factorial of 0 is 1. (You can't take the factorial of a negative number; only positive integers.)

So we have our **clearly defined base case**. And **we know what to do with numbers that aren't our base case** (we multiply them times the factorial of the number one less than it.) We're ready to write our function.

```
def factorial(x):
    if x == 0:            # this is our base case
        return 1          # and this is what we do when we see it
    else:                 # this is what we do with all other numbers
        return x * factorial(x-1)
```

So you

1. Clearly define your base case.
2. Find a way to reduce your problem from a non-base case to the base case.
3. Formally express that in a function that (when it's simple!) looks like

   ```
   function:
       if base case: 
           this
       else: 
           something + function(something closer to the base case)
   ```

If you want something more advanced, Google's got a lot of info.

Comment: +1 for the recursive answer :-) and it's good, too. and recursive!

Answer (score 5):

I would highly recommend watching MIT's [intro to programming course](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-fall-2008/lecture-videos/).

[Lecture 4](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-fall-2008/lecture-videos/embed04/) talks about recursion.